# Shape recognition in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

Guys want write a basic code in matlab that recognizes basic shapes

Have converted a .png image to binary and then applied edge detection (Canny)
what to do next so that i can use the edge detected image to state that the image is a circle.

```
i = imread('h.png');
i= im2bw(i,0.5);
i=edge(i,'canny');
imshow(i);
```

what to do next???

Answer (score 1):

you probably should learn about [hough transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hough_transform).

Matlab has already a function for circles [`imfindcircles`](http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/images/ref/imfindcircles.html) (check out the examples!)

Comment: r=radius; imfindcircle(i,r);

Comment: Actually the examples provide ready to use code - so I think that is not necessary.

Comment: for circles this would work, but what about other shapes like square triangle ,pentagon

Comment: and thanks fr the reply

Answer (score 0):

You could try using a neural net that was trained on a series of shapes. The nn can return a percentage accuracy so that you can see how well its doing for example.

```
function scan(img)
   files = dir('*.jpg');
   hist = [];
   for n = 1 : length(files)
     filename = files(n).name;
     file = imread(filename);

     hist = [hist, imhist(rgb2gray(imresize(file,[ 50 50])))]; %#ok
   end

   som = selforgmap([10 10]);
   som = train(som, hist);
   t   = som(hist); %extract class data

   net = lvqnet(10);
   net = train(net, hist, t);

   like(img, hist, files, net)
end
```

Can be tweeked to [recognize shapes](http://scriptbucket.wordpress.com/2012/09/21/image-classification-using-matlab-somlvq/) in an image.

Comment: thanks fr the reply will try it and get back